# List taxonomy terms in node where the vocabulary is referenced

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a taxonomy vocabulary called "Type of appendix". When adding a new node to the page, users can choose a type of appendix. When showing the node, it should list the all appendixes in a table with the category in the first column, the name in the second column and a link to the item in the last column. As shown in the image below[image: Example of table]

At the moment, my page displays the following:
[image: Current state]

I want to replace `ICT manual` with the table in the example.

Comment: Are you looking for a code based solution or a gui one?

Comment: Both are good. Preferably a gui one for maintainability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish that with the [Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views):

> You need Views if
>
> You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it differently.
>       You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
>       You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain type.
>       You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display articles the way you like.
>       You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of some particular type.
>       You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
>       You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of
>   "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and
>   displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts for
>   that month.
>
> Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some of the obvious
>   uses of Views.

Depending on your folder structure, you can use a contextual filter and can create a block, then limit which pages on which it is viewable.

Comment: I've managed to create something like that with `EVA: Entity Views Attachment`. The problem is that I don't know how to configure the contextual filter.

Comment: Are you trying to show the appendix for the current page, or show all of the possible appendices on each page?

Comment: The appendices that has the same taxonomy term. Your answer helped me find it, Thank you very much.
Instead of a block I used EVA for displaying it - https://drupal.org/project/eva